# C++ check all status bits in struct

Tags: c++

I have to store error status bits as `bool` variables inside a `struct`. Now i would need a way to check if any/none/all variables are set.

I know there is the `std::bitset` but it only allows me to access the values by index and not by name. So i made a construct like this:

```
#include <cassert>
union ErrorStatus
{
    struct {
        bool error1;
        bool error2;
        bool error3;
    };
    std::array<bool, 3> bits;
    bool any()const{
        return std::any_of(bits.begin(), bits.end(), [](const bool& b){return b == true; });
        }
    bool none() const {
        return !any();
    }
    bool all()const{
        return !std::any_of(bits.begin(), bits.end(), [](const bool& b){return b == false; });
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    ErrorStatus errorStatus;
    assert(errorStatus.none() == true);
    errorStatus.error2 = true;
    assert(errorStatus.none() == false);

    return 0;
}
```

But with this i have the problem that i would need to change the number in the `std::array` declaration to match the number of boolean values inside the `struct`.

Is there a way to sync the `array` size with the amount of bools in the struct?
Are there alternatives that are more elegant (and hopefully good to read)?

Comment: Use a vector of bools, rather than an array. Note that your STL implementation may optimise it for size, in which case certain operations you may expect to be able to use will be unavailable.

Comment: Maybe use `std::vector`?

Comment: @Steve if the number of bool isn't dynamic, I don't see why you should use vector. Use `std::array` for fixed size array

Comment: How do you add the values to your bits array or am I missing something here?

Comment: You don't need to reimplement `any`, `none` and `all`, the standard library [already has those](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Comment: @Steve `std::bitset` seems better, as it is honest about what it's trying to be, unlike the identity crisis that is `std::vector<bool>`. Anyway, the OP said that neither is suitable, as they want to access the flags by name.

Comment: ...and, besides, what the OP is trying to do with the `union` is UB, as far as I know; type-punning through `union`s is legal in C, but not C++; the latter only allows reading from a different member than was last written to if the members read/written are at equivalent places in the members of 2 "standard-layout struct" types, which I don't think any array is or `std::array` must be.

Comment: Is the amount of errors defined compile time?

Comment: @xander i agree, the number of bool is fixed at compile time, thats why i used `std::array` in the first place. Yup, the assignment of the values to the bits is still something that i haven't figured out

Comment: @nwp thanks for the hint, i'll use it

Comment: @xander with VS2013 the array and the bool values are in sync. but from the suggestions i did change to a enum based solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there alternatives that are more elegant (and hopefully good to read)?

You can use `enum` to name elements in array:

```
enum {
  error1,
  error2,
  error3,
  errorsSize // must be last
};

using ErrorStatus = std::array<bool, errorsSize>;

ErrorStatus errors;
errors[error1] = false;
```

adding new enumerators before `errorsSize` will "automatically" resize array.

Comment: thanks for the hint. now i use a small wrapper class that accepts the enum as template and uses its value `COUNT` to allocate the array. And there is a macro to define the `enum` in the first place and add the required value at the end

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a very readable solution which makes your error structure usabe in standard algorithms:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// Configure structure packing for Visual Studio.
// See your compiler documentation on how to do this.
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)

struct Errors
{
    bool error1;
    bool error2;
    bool error3;

    inline const bool* begin() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const bool*>(this);
    }

    inline const bool* end() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const bool*>(this + 1);
    }

    inline bool any() const
    {
        return std::count(begin(), end(), true) > 0;
    }

    inline bool all() const
    {
        return std::count(begin(), end(), true) == end() - begin();
    }

    inline bool none() const
    {
        return std::count(begin(), end(), true) == 0;
    }
};

#pragma pack(pop)
```

I tested with

```
int main()
{

    Errors e;
    memset(&e, 0, sizeof(e));

    e.error1 = false;
    e.error2 = false;
    e.error3 = false;
    std::cout << "any=" << e.any() << ", all=" << e.all() << ", none=" << e.none() << std::endl;

    e.error1 = true;
    e.error2 = false;
    e.error3 = false;
    std::cout << "any=" << e.any() << ", all=" << e.all() << ", none=" << e.none() << std::endl;

    e.error1 = true;
    e.error2 = true;
    e.error3 = true;
    std::cout << "any=" << e.any() << ", all=" << e.all() << ", none=" << e.none() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, this is a compiler specific implementation and I would not recommend using a structure this way.

My favourite way of storing multiple error codes is

```
enum class Enum
{
  Error1,
  Error2,
  Error3
};

typedef std::set<Error> Errors;
```

Comment: The pointer arithmetic you're doing is not legal/well-defined C++, given that its operands are not members of the same array. Moreover, is it guaranteed that these `bool` members will be contiguous in the `struct`, with exactly `sizeof(bool)` between them? I'm not sure but don't think so.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "not members of the same array". `this` is of type `Errors` and points to an array of `Errors` with exactly 1 element. So `this+1` is perfectly legal. You are right about the padding. Its not covered by the standard, but every compiler I know of alignes the structure elements on their size. So if only a single type (here: `bool`) is used all over the structure, there should be no padding at all. You can tell the compiler to insert not padding with  `#pragma(pack)` or `#pragma pack(1)` for example.

Comment: Eh... I mean, sure, this'll probably work in practice, since compilers don't often go out of their way to ruin our day. It seems like a real code smell, though!

Comment: Behaviour has been defined this way because it is necessarry for defining file headers for example. But there is no portable way in defining the packing (at least none that I know of). And .. yeah ... I would not use it this way. But Zaiborg explicitly asked for a solution with boolean values in a structure and this is the best way I can think of.